# Entity field ArrayCollection, doctrine insert name class in database

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

I have a object with field type array, it's initialize to docrine collection, but when I save the objcet, the value inserted into my database is :

```
O:43:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":1:{s:53:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection elements";a:2:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;}}
```

When I dump after the form submit

```
 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
```

the value seems correct

```
-days: ArrayCollection {#14714 ▼
-elements: array:2 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 2
]
```

My entity field

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */
private $days;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->days = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->end_time = new \DateTime();
}

public function addDay(int $day): self
{
    if (!$this->days->contains($day)) {
        $this->days[] = $day;
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeDay(int $day): self
{
    if ($this->days->contains($day)) {
        $this->days->removeElement($day);
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|array
 */
public function getDays(): Collection
{
    return $this->days;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: That's a normal behaviour. `@ORM\Column(type="array")` gives an array format. Considering the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/types.html#array), the type array *"Maps and converts array data based on PHP serialization"*

Comment: ok thank you, I added toArray() to function 
getDays()
    {
        return $this->days->toArray();
    }